# Чем заменить *swf

Tags: html, gif, swf

На старом сайте есть шапка, баннер сделан в формате swf у большинства браузеров Flash отключен, то есть "Нажмите чтобы показать содержимое flash" или как то так, чем заменить его чтобы открывался у всех сразу?

Gif? получается большой вес 10-20 мегабайт.

Comment: Javascript'ом, рисующем на canvas'е.

Comment: Можно немного поподробнее? (баннер - анимация)

Comment: В современном мире CSS, JS и SVG заменили flash. Какие ещё подробности вам нужны?

Comment: Начните с http://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Есть инструменты, переводящие flash в html5, по крайней мере Adobe Animate CC должен уметь это делать. Возможно перед этим придется декомпилировать проект. Может тут что-то полезное найдете: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439727/is-there-a-way-to-convert-swf-to-html5

Comment: баннер swf это видео, давным давно перекадированное в swf, исходник есть

Comment: Я бы попробовал найти как через Adobe программы опубликовать его в виде HTML5. В крайнем случае достать видео и напрямую его встроить через <video> тег.